# Unable to use git checkout to revert some paths in a branch to that of another branch

Tags: git

I have some changes in my current branch from a particular path in another branch. (There was a dependency that needed bringing across.)

I initially brought these changes across using the following commands:

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b new_branch
git checkout other_feature path/to/dependency
```

Now I need to unpick this dependency, or at least aspects of it (a subpath within `path/to/dependency`).

I have run `git diff --name-status master..new_branch path/to/dependency` and it displays the differences as expected.

However, `git checkout master path/to/dependency` does not successfully revert this directory's contents to that of master. Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case, try:

```
 git checkout --force  master path/to/dependency/subpath/to/revert
 # or:
 git checkout --ours master path/to/dependency/subpath/to/revert
```

from [`git checkout` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

```
-f
--force
```

> When switching branches, proceed even if the index or the working tree differs from HEAD. This is used to throw away local changes.
>
> When checking out paths from the index, do not fail upon unmerged entries; instead, unmerged entries are ignored.

That first option '--force' should be what you are looking for, but in case merges are involved, then the second option (`--ours`, not compatible with `--force`) can help too.

```
--ours
--theirs
```

> When checking out paths from the index, check out stage `#2` (`ours`) or `#3` (`theirs`) for unmerged paths.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, I get the following error message when attempting the force ours checkout: `fatal: git checkout: --ours/--theirs, --force and --merge are incompatible when checking out of the index.`

Comment: @bcmcfc what is the result of a `git status`, then? And a `git branch`?

Comment: `On branch new_branch nothing to commit (working directory clean)` and the full local branch list with the active branch (`new_branch`) starred.